# If $A\geq 0$, is $\|A^r\|=\|A\|^r$ for all positive real number $r$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and ${\mathbb B}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$. An operator $A\in{\mathbb B}(E)$ is called positive
if $\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in E$. We write $A\geq0$.

> If $A\geq 0$, is  $\|A^r\|=\|A\|^r$ for all positive real number $r$?

It is well-know that if $A$ is selfadjoint (in particular positive), then  $\|A^n\|=\|A\|^n$ for all positive integer $n$.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what your Lemma 2.2 got to do with it, but $\|A^r\| = \|A\|^r$ follows directly from the continuous functional calculus. That is, for the continuous function
$$f: \mathrm{spec}(A) \to \mathbb{R}, \quad f(t) = t^r$$
you get
$$\|A^r\| = \|f(A)\| = \|f\|_{\infty} = \sup\limits_{t \in \mathrm{spec}(A)} |f(t)| = \sup\limits_{t \in \mathrm{spec}(A)} t^r = \|A\|^r.$$

Comment: this lemma is taken from a paper